# Dropout setting layer weights array to empty

Tags: keras, dropout

I'm attempting to access the trained weight values of this network :

```
X = [[1] , [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]]
Y = [[1] , [2] ,[3] ,[4] ,[5] ,[6] ,[7] ,[8]]

from keras.callbacks import History 
history = History()

from keras import optimizers

inputDim = len(X[0])
print('input dim' , inputDim)
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=inputDim))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.009, decay=1e-10, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd , metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X,Y , validation_split=0.1 , verbose=2 , callbacks=[history] , epochs=5,batch_size=32)
```

Can access the weights in first layer :

```
weights = model.get_layer(index=1).get_weights()
weights
[array([[-0.93537247]], dtype=float32), array([ 0.00989669], dtype=float32)]
```

But not in 2'nd layer :

```
weights = model.get_layer(index=2).get_weights()
weights
[]
```

It appears the addition of dropout is causing this as removing dropout :

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=inputDim))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Results in accessing the weights successfully

```
weights = model.get_layer(index=1).get_weights()
weights

[array([[-0.62137389]], dtype=float32), array([-0.05591233], dtype=float32)]

weights = model.get_layer(index=2).get_weights()
weights

[array([[-1.09568715]], dtype=float32), array([ 0.53271592], dtype=float32)]
```

Reading about Dropout : https://keras.io/layers/core/ :

"Dropout consists in randomly setting a fraction rate of input units to 0 at each update during training time, which helps prevent overfitting."

Dropout visualization : 
[image]
 src : http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a/srivastava14a.pdf

So a subset of neuron's are dropped. But in my example it appears all neurons are dropped as the weight parameters in layer 2 is an empty array ? 
Why is the addition of dropout causing weight parameters in subsequent layers to become inaccessible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropouts don't have weights. The Dense layers (and some other types) have.

Your first model has these layers:

```
0: input layer - no weights 
1: Dense(...) - weights and biases    
2: Dropout(...) - no weights    
3: Dense(...) - weights and biases
4: Dropout(...) - no weights
```

Weights are trainable parameters that belong to a single layer.

The dropouts simply have a constant parameter that cannot be trained. This parameter just removes part of the results.

---

Dense layers use their weights to change the input and throw an output:

```
#pseudocode
output = Weights x input + biases
```

Dropout layers will simply discard some of the outputs:

```
#pseudocode - suppose the dropout parameter is 0.2
output = input[take 80% of the elements]
```